# What spell was used to defeat this Death Eater?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

What spell was used by

> Molly Weasley

to defeat this death eater?

> Bellatrix Lestrange

It must have been something very powerful because it completely incinerated them.

Comment: It's called a "[Disintegration curse](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Disintegration_curse)" on HP Wikia by fan editors but that's for the movieverse.

Comment: Guess who?! :P Oh you thought I was gone! Hahahaha!

Comment: @Bellatrix @#$& Return whence you came, demon!!

Comment: @MishaR Nope, I won’t!! :P